# jQuery not working after call back with RadAjaxLoadingPanel

Tags: jquery, telerik

I've got a `RadAjaxLoadingPanel` in my page. When it returns from a call back, the `OnClientHiding` event is raised and my jQuery initialization code runs apparently fine. The jQuery adds some click handlers to some checkboxes. The jQuery has the intended effect on an initial request and appears to run OK, at least after a call back, but the actual click events don't fire after the call back when I click on a checkbox.

How could this be?

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    f();

});

    function LoadingPanelHiding(sender, eventArgs) {

    f();

    }

    function f() {

        $('.selectAll').click(function () {

            alert('Hello world!');

        });

    }
```

Comment: post your code. do you suppose us to use telepathy to read it?

Comment: @robert No I was hoping for some deduction given that, as you can see, the code is trivial. :)

Comment: Well I suppose the code I've posted is simpler than the code in my app but the point is that I don't think its the code that's the problem because it runs fine when the page is first loaded.

Comment: @Rory I went through my questions and found three answers to accept which I guessed were right. I'd only left them because I'd already moved on to a different solution and didn't have time to check the answer. A lot of answers get added as comments where its not possible to officially accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how much this helps since the question is a few months old, but I encountered the same problem and was able to solve it based on the information in this link:
http://blog.aspnet.sk/rostacik/archive/2010/08/05/running-javascript-when-page-loads-with-telerik-controls.aspx

By switching from the $(document).ready() to the Sys.Application.add_load() function, my jquery function is reloaded after each ajax callback:

```
//$(document).ready(function () {
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {    
    $("[id$=sortable]").sortable(
```

Comment: Cool. I will give it a go if the problem ever turns up again.

Comment: @Ian Warbuton, this was exactly my issue, but how did you solve it? I get 'Sys is not defined' error.

Comment: Have you tried this answer? I didn't get the chance to test it because I changed jobs.